# StringSplit acting weird on a String in StandardForm

Tags: string-manipulation

To begin, this is my first post on stack exchange, so if my question is not up to par please let me know so I can make the appropriate edits. Now for my question: why is it that parsing a string in StandardForm often gives strange results? How can this be avoided? Take the following case. 
Consider some quantity

```
 M= X[{2,0},{2,0}]+X[{3,0},{1,0}]
```

I want to convert it to a string in StandardForm and then parse the result by splitting at the plus sign. First, the obvious result without StandardForm comes from

```
Str[F_]:=ToString[F]
StringSplit[Str[M],"+"]
```

and is

```
{"X[{2, 0}, {2, 0}] ", " X[{3, 0}, {1, 0}]"}
```

Great. But now I impose standard form,

```
Str[F_]:=ToString[F,StandardForm]
StringSplit[Str[M],"+"]
```

and suddenly the output is

```
      {"\!\(\(\(X[\(\(\(\({2, 0}\)\), \(\({2, 0}\)\)\)\)]\)\) ", " \(\(X[\(\
\(\(\({3, 0}\)\), \(\({1, 0}\)\)\)\)]\)\)\)"}
```

Why is this happening and how can I avoid it? For various reasons, it is really a necessity for me to use StandardForm here, so I can't just leave that out.

Thanks!

Comment: The extra "\"s are from the [string representation of the boxes](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/StringRepresentationOfBoxes.html). Why not splitting the expression and then convert to standard form? For example `ToString[#, StandardForm] & /@ (M /. Plus -> List)`

Comment: I was quite frankly not even aware of the concept of boxes until I read your comment - thank you for the help! At the risk of being very off topic, could I ask another question related to this project? How do I stop mathematica from combining terms in expressions into powers - ie I want things to stay in the form X[...]X[...] instead of (X[...])^2, both during evaluation and at output. Thanks again!

Comment: Use `HoldForm` for this: `HoldForm[x[1] x[1]]` (but it is off-topic, of course).